# javascript regular expression for cross browser opacity

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm reading through a JS book and I came across the following regex in an example.

```
(parseFloat(filter.match(/opacity=([^)]+/)[1]) / 100)
```

Where `filter="alpha(opacity=50)"`. I understand what the code is doing and that the returned match to be parsed is the second index in the array, which is the capture `([^)`, but I don't understand how that capture makes any sense. How does `([^)]+` match the opacity value? From what I understand if a caret is used as the first character then it will match a string that begins with whatever follows, or if it's used in a character class it will match anything *except* what's in the class, such as `[^abc]`.

However in this situation it looks like the caret isn't doing either of those things because the right square bracket is outside the parentheses. Suffice to say, I'm rather perplexed.

Comment: It's missing the group closing `)`. Because `[1]` refers to what's captured inside the first parenthesized group  (capture group). the `[^)]` is a [negated](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `)` correct regex should look [like this](https://regex101.com/r/kF5gD7/1): `/opacity=([^)]+)/` [see fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7Lw4fz7b/).

Comment: So it *is* a typo! I knew something was off. I blame Manning Publications :-P Thanks @Jonny5!

Comment: If unsure, you can always [paste your regex in regex101](https://regex101.com/r/sQ9bY4/2). It shows errors, for this: `( Unbalanced group`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[^)]+` is getting any sequence of characters that is not a close parenthesis `)`.

As @jonny points out, there is a missing closing parenthesis. and should be `/opacity=([^)]+)/`.

The pattern is `/` `opacity=([^)]+)` `/` where `opacity=` are all literal characters and `[^)]+` should match the value you need. Focus on the square brackets, not the parenthesis.

With that, I believe the `filter.match(` `/opacity([^)]+)/` `)` will return `opacity=50` in position `[0]` and `50` in position `[1]`.

`filter.match(/opacity=([^)]+/)` `)[1]` returns the portion in the array position `[1]`.

Then the `parseFloat` kicks in and converts the string `50` into a number which is finally divided by `100`.

Comment: But those parentheses create a capture so how can I ignore them? If what you say is the case then `)` is part of the expression inside the square brackets AND the close of a capture? If so, then how does the capture contain `"50"` when what's inside them is `[^`?

Comment: @AndrewJensen—the capture group is defined by the outer brackets `([^)]+)`, so it's capturing all characters after  `opacity=` up to, but not including, a `)`. It assumes there is at least one such character. If there isn't, the expression returns NaN.